# DZone frontpage rss feeds broken?

Tags: rss, feed

I used to get the latest DZone articles in my RSS reader from http://feeds.dzone.com/dzone/frontpage/ but it appears broken since DZone changed their site.

Someone knows how to receive new articles from DZone by RSS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I asked this question to the DZone support team today. Here's their answer:

> We will be adding RSS sources back into the site within the next week, along with quite a few other exciting features.

I'll post back if I hear from them again.

---

**Update:**
The home page feed seems to have been revived September 8th at this URL: http://feeds.dzone.com/home

Enjoy!

Comment: I also emailed DZone and and got a response this week stating that "we're working on getting RSS feeds back". I recommend others send emails to DZone so that they know how many of us would like the RSS feed back.

Comment: Seems that nobody respects RSS nowadays. Facebook, Twitter, etc are the ways to watch the resources you want for new content. It makes me sad, but that's how the things work now.

Comment: With http://feeds.dzone.com/home  you get only feeds from dzone, no public articles that are listed in dzone.com/links

Answer (score 3):

The main DZone RSS Feed:

- DZone.com - http://feeds.dzone.com/home

Latest DZone Publications (Refcardz, Research Guides, etc.):

- DZone Publications - http://feeds.dzone.com/publications

Feeds for DZone's various topic portals:

- Agile Zone - http://feeds.dzone.com/agile
- Big Data Zone - http://feeds.dzone.com/big-data
- Cloud Zone - http://feeds.dzone.com/cloud
- Database Zone - http://feeds.dzone.com/database
- DevOps Zone - http://feeds.dzone.com/devops
- Integration Zone - http://feeds.dzone.com/integration
- IoT Zone - http://feeds.dzone.com/iot
- Java Zone - http://feeds.dzone.com/java
- Mobile Zone - http://feeds.dzone.com/mobile
- Performance Zone - http://feeds.dzone.com/performance
- Web Dev Zone - http://feeds.dzone.com/webdev

Comment: Any way to feeds from any domain, not only from those Zone?